# Increasing process and stopping time inequality

Tags: stochastic-processes, stopping-times

Let M be an a.s. continuous and increasing process.
Let $\sigma_c:=inf\{t\ge 0:M_t\ge c^2\} $.

$1)$ Why the following hold??
 $$E[M_{\sigma_c}]\le E[c^2\land M_\infty] $$

$2)$ I guess that the answer could be connected to te following question: if a process never hit the threshold imposed by the stopping time $\sigma_c$ then, what is the value that $\sigma_c$ assume? I guess $M_\infty$ but still it is not clear to me $1)$.

Comment: Is $M$ continuous?

Comment: @JohnDawkins yes, it is also increasing in t. sorry I missed this information that could be useful

Comment: Continuous martingales of bounded variation are constant processes.

Comment: If $M$ never reaches $c^2$ then $M_{\sigma_c} = M_{\infty}$. Else, $M_{\sigma_c} = c^2$ by continuity.

Comment: @UBM Increasing processes have bounded/finite variation. Where did you get $M$ is bounded from?

Comment: @Calculon: I meant the stopped process but I see my mistake now, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

(I don't think you want $M$ to be increasing, per Calculon's comment.) For continuous $M$: on $\{\sigma_c<\infty\}$ you have $M_{\sigma_c}=c^2$; on $\{\sigma_c=\infty\}$ we interpret $M_{\sigma_c}$ to be $M_\infty$ — notice that in this latter case you have $M_\infty<c^2$.

But to assert that $M_{\sigma_c}\le c^2\wedge M_\infty$ (and then take expectations, which seems to be the plan) won't work, because that first inequality need not hold.  For example, take $M$ to be Brownian motion started at 2, stopped when it first reaches 1, so that $M_\infty=1$. Take $c=3$. Then  $E[c^2\wedge M_\infty]=1$ but   $E[M_{\sigma_c}]=1+8P[\sigma_c<\infty]=2$.

Perhaps you want the upper bound to be $E[c^2\vee M_\infty]$, which in the example is 9, yielding a true but crude bound.

Comment: on MSE we reach a point where we have to make the question correct, and then answer it according to our own guess....

Comment: how did  you compute $E[M_{\sigma_c}]=1+8P[\sigma_c<\infty]=2$? Anyway I removed the martingale assumption leaving instead the increasing one. Still it seems not so obvious that step